# Python Reading Specific Parts of the screen and Taking actions Based on them

Tags: python

i am kind of new to Python and trying to learn the language the best i can. Right now i am having a problem of trying to automate something. I dont know how i should
[What i am trying to automate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtuZ7.png) I was trying to make the Programm being able to Read the value of how much Food, Wood etc is in the Storage right now(maybe also know if the storage is full or not) If it is full, or has reached the value needed to upgrade the storage for Food for ecaple, then it should do so.
I was thinking at first of how it should know that the storage is full, should be done by using pyautogui using but i am unsure...i am sorry that this is such a long massage and i dont know if you guys understand what i am trying to explain,...if not so, just ask

Answer (score 1):

Python does not recognize (nor know) the value of the characters for this type of automation it is recommended to use an image recognition library. (I Recommend Opencv) and for clicking on the screen you can use pyput.

Opencv Link: https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

Pyput Link: https://pypi.org/project/pynput/

and you can also watch the following project since it can help you get started.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXqKniVe6P8

Comment: Hm...thanm you, but i was thinking about using OPen CV and Im.Rec, but that would really go forward, since the value is always changing, i will watch tho the Video and maybe try to take an other approach on this